# EF core Migrations wrong latin SQL encoding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 1.0 project with EF7.
When I add a migration with SQL command and latin characters, I get them replaced by "?" when updating database.

Let's see an example:

```
public partial class TestEncodingMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"some text with latin chars : á é í ñ");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the script I get from that migration:

```
PM> dnx ef migrations script <some prev migration> -c MyDbContext

some text with accent: ? ? ? ?
;

GO

INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20160216162901_TestEncodingMigration', N'7.0.0-rc1-16348');
```

As you can see, all latin characters have been replaced by "?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by saving migration file again with UTF-8 encoding.

It seems that add-migration creates files with ANSI encoding.

So, open migration *.cs in notepad and then File->Save As and at the bottom set Encoding to UTF-8 then overwrite.

Comment: Thanks! or even easier: inside visual studio, right-click over .cs file->open with..->Editor with encoding->select UTF-8->save file

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug of RC1, as discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4574), and it's planned to be resolved in RC2